# Usage of Optimal FSM Pattern

Tags: c++

Considering the following state design pattern taken from the book 'Practical Statecharts in C/C++' by Miro Samek (p.70ff). I have the question of how to initialize the state and how to dispatch events to the state machine. I thought it's something like `Fsm myFsm(0)` and then `myFsm.init()` but calling `this->*myState(sig)` is generating a runtime error. Any ideas on how to properly initialize the class Fsm and how to call the dispatch method. Thank you in advance.

```
class Fsm {
public:
   typedef void (Fsm::*State)(unsigned const sig);
   Fsm(State initial) : myState(initial) {}
   virtual ~Fsm() {}
   void init() { disptach(0); }
   void dispatch(int sig) { (this->*myState)(sig); }
protected:
   void tran(State target) { myState = target; }
   #define TRAN(target_) tran(static_cast<State>(target_))
   State myState;
};

class CParser4 : public Fsm {
public:
   CParser4() : Fsm((State)&Cparser4::initial) {}
   long getCommentCtr() const { return myCommentCtr; }
private:
   void initial(int);
   void code(int sig);
   void slash(int sig);
   void comment(int sig);
   void star(int sig);
private:
   long myCommentCtr;
};
```

Comment: more like `CParser4 myFsm;` as doing `Fsm myFsm(0)` means the initial state is a null pointer and thus not callable

Comment: alternatively, `std::unique_ptr<Fsm> myFsm(new CParser4());`

Comment: You should remove the C++ language tag because the C language doesn't have the keywords `class`, `private`, nor `public`.  Issues are easier when you are only programming in one language.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well without any issue.

It seems that it differs from your real code, since otherwise I can't explain mistakes which couldn't be introduced by copy/paste:

**disptach** -> dispatch

**Cparser4** -> CParser4

With both of them the code won't just compile.

When both are fixed it works well. In case with the fixed code you have the issues, provide compilable and runable version with the code that causes the failure.